# How to configure ldap in jboss eap with Kerberos?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, kerberos, jboss-eap-6

Currently I have configured my application with Kerberos authentication for a specific user's in jboss-eap by specifying users name in standalone.xml and it's working fine. But wants to configure the same on the basis of the ldap i.e users in a AD will able to authenticate directly and i need not to specify the username in standalone.xml.

**Standalone.xml working fine:-** Specifying the username in stanadalone.xml

```
<security-domains>
    <security-domain name="SPNEGO" cache-type="default">
        <authentication>
            <login-module code="SPNEGO" flag="required">
                <module-option name="serverSecurityDomain" value="host"/>
            </login-module>
        </authentication>
        <mapping>
            <mapping-module code="SimpleRoles" type="role">
                <module-option name="saurabhgupta@ECO.COM" value="User"/>
            </mapping-module>
        </mapping>
    </security-domain>
    <security-domain name="host" cache-type="default">
        <authentication>
            <login-module code="Kerberos" flag="required">
                <module-option name="debug" value="true"/>
                <module-option name="storeKey" value="true"/>
                <module-option name="refreshKrb5Config" value="true"/>
                <module-option name="useKeyTab" value="true"/>
                <module-option name="doNotPrompt" value="true"/>
                <module-option name="keyTab" value="/spengo/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/krb.keytab"/>
                <module-option name="principal" value="HTTP/vm428.eco.com@ECO.COM"/>
            </login-module>
        </authentication>
```

**Standalone.xml:-** To configure ldap

```
<security-domains>
    <security-domain name="SPNEGO" cache-type="default">
        <authentication>
            <login-module code="SPNEGO" flag="required">
                <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                <module-option name="serverSecurityDomain" value="host"/>
            </login-module>
            <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
                <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
                <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://AD IP:389"/>
                <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
                <module-option name="bindDN" value="CN=siddharth,CN=Users,DC=eco,DC=com"/>
                <module-option name="bindCredential" value="password"/>
                <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="CN=Users,DC=eco,DC=com"/>
                <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
                <module-option name="searchScope" value="ONELEVEL_SCOPE"/>
                <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="true"/>
            </login-module>
        </authentication>
    </security-domain>
    <security-domain name="host" cache-type="default">
        <authentication>
            <login-module code="Kerberos" flag="required">
                <module-option name="debug" value="true"/>
                <module-option name="storeKey" value="true"/>
                <module-option name="refreshKrb5Config" value="true"/>
                <module-option name="useKeyTab" value="true"/>
                <module-option name="doNotPrompt" value="true"/>
                <module-option name="keyTab" value="/spengo/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/krb.keytab"/>
                <module-option name="principal" value="HTTP/vm428.eco.com@ECO.COM"/>
            </login-module>
        </authentication>
    </security-domain>
```

**My environment consists of:-** linux server with JBoss EAP 6.2 client station with Windows 7 64bit + Chrome Windows Server 2008 Active Directory (act as KDC)

But facing an error of 401 in browser window.

```
**Error:-** JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 401 - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report
JBWEB000068: message 
JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000121: This request requires HTTP authentication.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JBoss Web/7.2.2.Final-redhat-1
```

Did anyone have this problem and solve it somehow?

Comment: See this doc: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Configuring_Authentication.html

Comment: @AnupDey thanks for the reply but i need to configure the security at appserver level/

Comment: JBOSS EAP 6.x supports Kerberos and single sign-on - no need to configure any user ID in standalone.xml. I can send you an example snippet from standalone.xml configured this way and way to configure security at app server level. Will that work?